# How to remove the ?q= from the url in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

My current url looks like this:

> [domain name]/?q=[search_term]

and would like to make it look like this:

> [domain name]/[search_term]

In my **urls.py** I have the following code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
     url(r'^q=(?P<search_term>[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$', 'home', name='query'),
```

In **views.py** the code looks like this:

```
def home(request, search_term='q'):
     do stuff
     return render(request, 'template', {context})
```

For some reason, no matter if I have a search_term in the url or not, the app always serves the first route. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Routing examines the script path, not the query string.

Comment: How should I change the script path to make it work as I want?

Comment: Change your root view to examine the query string and redirect appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Correct urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
     url(r'^(?P<search_term>[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$', 'home', name='query'),  # without =q
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?` in the URL separates the `path` which Django matches against URL patterns from the `query` parameters, which are read from the `request` object after a route is selected and activated.

That is, your second URL pattern will never match any URL which has a literal `?` in it.

Your second URL pattern should match

`[domain name]/q=[search_term]`

but won't match

`[domain name]/?q=[search_term]`

Comment: How should I change the pattern to match my url?

Comment: It's not technically possible. The string which is tested to match against a urlpattern doesn't have the `?q=` part in it, so no pattern will match.  If you really want your application to take queries without a `?` then you need to change your search form or whatever is creating the URLs to not have a `?`.  But since that's how search forms work, you may be better off just tolerating it and using request.GET to read them in, possibly from a different URL prefix like `^search$`  (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with GET requests. You need to use a post with a variable in order for this to work

Comment: POST won't add the values to the script path either.